# How to delete Cisco 1841 IP

Tags: router

I am trying to delete IP assigned to interface fa0/1. But it returns an error saying **"Delete Secondary first"**
i have alreay tried this command **(config-if)# no ip address 192.168.5.23 255.255.255.0**

Comment: can we see sh run, please remove passwords.

Answer (score 2):

You have a secondary IP address defined on the interface. Your configuration will have something in it like:

```
interface FastEthernet0/1
  ip address 192.168.5.23 255.255.255.0
  ip address 192.168.5.24 255.255.255.0 secondary
```

You will need to `no` out the secondary IP address first.